# How to get "Add Code Generation Item..." menu item in VS2008?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, t4

I have Entity Framework template for VS2008 SP1 (.NET 3.5 SP1) installed.

But I don't know how to get "Add Code Generation Item..." menu item when right click to surface of EDMX file.

Actually, I need T4 support in VS2008 such in VS2010.

Any help is appreciated.

Goran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can (or at least, easily. I suppose you could write a custom add-in to do the same, but...)

Here is a document on T4 support in VS2008 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126484(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you. Actually I wanted to transform ObjectContext class to DbContext. Is it possible?